# Strange result from C#'s DataSet WriteXML conversion

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio

I have written the following code to extract some queries and convert the result into XML file.

```
OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(args[0]);
OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter();
conn.Open();
da.SelectCommand = new OdbcCommand(args[1], conn);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
ds.WriteXml("iDA.XML");
```

However I'm getting the following which is not exactly how I want the data to look like.  I don't know where the "*x0000" at the start and end of each element come from and or the "* xml:space="preserve" come from.  Any ideas?

```
<so_bo_suffix_x0000_ xml:space="preserve"></so_bo_suffix_x0000_> 
<so_processing_date_x0000_>2012-07-08T00:00:00+10:00</so_processing_date_x0000_>
```

Unfortunately I wouldn't be able to put more info on, however, I can tell you in regards to the above couple of lines, the data SHOULD look like the following respectively.  This is from a similar application which runs the same queries.

```
<so_bo_suffix>  </so_bo_suffix>
<so_processing_date>17/04/2012 12:00:00 AM</so_processing_date><so_processing_date>17/04/2012 12:00:00 AM</so_processing_date>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you post some more information on the schema you're working with?

Comment: I've added more information.  Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

The `xml:space="preserve"` means that it the parser should keep any white-space within the tag. It generates this when the whitespace is not normalized. (Whitespace is only spaces, not beginning or ending in spaces, and not containing two or more spaces in sequence.)

The `_x0000_` suffix comes from [`XmlConvert.EncodeLocalName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert.encodelocalname). It means that it found a character that is invalid in XML. In this case it is a null character. I don't know where this null character comes from, though.